# Curried type "does not take type parameters"

Tags: scala, types, scala-3, dotty, match-types

I wanted to make a type that I could use to verify if a tuple is homogenous. I wrote this, which should ensure that all elements of `T` are equal to `X` ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hSBKbNSNQXOyTOJpSzjyxg)):

```scala
type Homogenous[X] = [T <: Tuple] =>> T match {
  case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
  case X *: t => Homogenous[X][t] //Doesn't work
  case _ => Nothing
}

def f[T <: Tuple : Homogenous[String]](t: T) = ???
```

For whatever reason, the third line doesn't compile, with this error:

> Homogenous[X] does not take type parameters

However, if I make `Homogenous` take 2 parameters, it compiles, but I can't use a context bound anymore ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GGCA7j6PStKcXsVkuHN56A)).

```
type Homogenous[X, T <: Tuple] = T match {
  case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
  case X *: t => Homogenous[X, t]
  case _ => Nothing
}
```

I don't understand why this happens. It's not as if the lambda `[T] =>>` is only being returned from a specific case of the match type, so the compiler should realize that `Homogenous[X]` always takes a parameter. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong, and is there a fix/workaround?

Comment: This is somewhat expected though. When you have a recursive function, you always have to declare it first, before calling it in the definition, like `val f = (a:Int) => (b:Int) => f(a)(b)` will not work because it does not know what f type is at the compile time, and it cannot do type deduction and definition at the same time. So you need to do `val f: Int=>Int=>Int = a => b => f(a)(b)` to make it work. But for a type defintion, dotty does not allow declaration(bound) and definition on the same line, so the compiler doesn't know Homogenous is a curried type constructor, thus the error you see.

Comment: @texasbruce Good point. But I guess that's not the whole story because type `U[Int]` is allowed for `type U <: [T] =>> Any` but if we add upper bound in our case `type Homogenous[X] <: ([T <: Tuple] =>> Any) = [T <: Tuple] =>> T match { ...` still doesn't compile. I suspect the thing can also be how match types are translated into `Match` http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html#representation-of-match-types

Comment: @texasbruce *"But for a type defintion, dotty does not allow declaration(bound) and definition on the same line"* For match types upper bound along with definition are allowed. See code snippet `type Concat[Xs <: Tuple, +Ys <: Tuple] <: Tuple = Xs match {...` http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html

Comment: @texasbruce It doesn't compile with the error "cannot combine bound and alias". Anyways, the two-parameter version compiled without a return type, so that can't be it

Comment: @DmytroMitin It's interesting the code from the sample works, but when you do `type Homogenous[X] <: ([T <: Tuple] =>> Any) = [T <: Tuple] =>> Any` even without match clause, it just gives error saying `cannot combine bound and alias`. Could be a bug?

Comment: @texasbruce I don't know if it's a bug, maybe it's just that there's no point in putting a bound if you're using `=` anyways. Here's a [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WbggilvoQBilw0EsSHiExg)

Comment: @user That's a different case though. In the two parameter case, the compiler already knows Homogenous can take two parameter and return some type. Even it doesnt know what type it returns, it doesnt affect the compilation of calling it with two parameters. In the case when it is curried, it needs to know the return type of partially applied type, because it needs to know it returns a higher order type to allow further "applying" it. If scala allows some syntax like `type H[X][Y]`, then it would work fine, but it doesnt right now

Comment: @texasbruce Well, `type W <: Any = Int` is not allowed. I was talking about match types. Well, maybe `type Concat[Xs <: Tuple, +Ys <: Tuple] <: Tuple = Xs match {...` and `type Homogenous[X, T <: Tuple] = T match {` are match types but `type Homogenous[X] = [T <: Tuple] =>> T match {..` is not.

Comment: @texasbruce But the compiler should be able to tell that the type of `Homogenous` is `[X] =>> [T <: Tuple] =>> TypeToBeInferred`, right?

Comment: @DmytroMitin That's true. Looks like type bounds and defintion at the same time is allowed only when the rhs is not a higher order type with match clause. Rather strange requirement.

Comment: @texasbruce Well, as I mentioned in my answer multiple lists of type parameters are underimplemented. Maybe `type Homogenous[X][T <: Tuple] = T match {...` or `type Homogenous = [X] =>> [T <: Tuple] =>> T match {...` will compile then.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug or underimplemented feature.

As a workaround try

```
trait Hom[X] {
  type Rec[T <: Tuple] = T match {
    case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
    case X *: t => Rec[t] 
    case _ => Nothing
  }
}

type Homogenous[X] = [T <: Tuple] =>> Hom[X]#Rec[T]
```

Maybe connected with

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/multiple-type-parameter-lists-in-dotty-si-4719

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4719

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. I'll wait a while and then open an issue on GitHub then.