# Scala 3 type lambdas. Example for "curried type parameters"

Tags: scala, types, scala-3

Scala 3 has a powerful mechanism of expressing type constructors via type lambdas.

Even simple type lambdas can do powerful things like expressing partial application of a type constructor (see for ex https://stackoverflow.com/a/75428709/336184 ).

[Docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html#:%7E:text=on%20kind%20polymorphism-,Curried%20Type%20Parameters,-The%20body%20of) mention "Curried Type Parameters" like

```
type TL = [X] =>> [Y] =>> (X, Y)
```

this looks like even more abstract thing.

**Question:**

Can anyone give a working example with an implementation of such a type lambda? Also - what is a practical purpose of such an abstraction? Any parallels in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
type TL = [X] =>> [Y] =>> ...
```

is the same as

```scala
type TL[X] = [Y] =>> ...
```

and should be the same as

```scala
type TL[X][Y] = ...
```

if there were multiple type-parameter lists (MTPL).

So `[X] =>> [Y] =>> ...` should be a way to introduce such type anonymously.

MTPL along with named type parameters could be useful for specifying some type parameters and inferring the rest of them.

[Cannot prove equivalence with a path dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120836/cannot-prove-equivalence-with-a-path-dependent-type)

[Curried type "does not take type parameters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64393451/curried-type-does-not-take-type-parameters)

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/multiple-type-parameter-lists-in-dotty-si-4719/2399

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4719

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/experimental/named-typeargs.html

For example specifying some type parameters and inferring the rest can be necessary for type-level calculations. Currently for type-level calculations people either make type parameters nested or use type members instead of type parameters.

[When are dependent types needed in Shapeless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131067/when-are-dependent-types-needed-in-shapeless)

In Haskell you can write

```hs
foo :: forall (f :: * -> * -> *) . ()
foo = ()
```

but in Scala without MTPL implemented, currently you can't write

```scala
def foo[F[_][_]]: Unit = ()
```

you can only write

```scala
def foo[F[_,_]]: Unit = ()
```

If there were MTPL then for a definition like `def foo[F[_][_]]...` it would be convenient having curried type lambdas `[X] =>> [Y] =>> ...`, you could use them at a call site `foo[[X] =>> [Y] =>> ...]`.

In Haskell all type constructors are curried and there are no type lambdas

[Lambda for type expressions in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069840/lambda-for-type-expressions-in-haskell)

Comment: Dmytro, you keep rocking ! The part "and should be the same as... if there were multiple type-parameter lists (MTPL)" is very very interesting. is it possible you write any factual __implementation__ for the type alias `type TL =  ...` for illustration, to make it more tangible and not so abstract?

Comment: @Max Well, maybe `TL[K][V] = Map[K, V]` (we'd like to specify `K` and infer `V`) or `TL[K, +V][P] = CircularMap[K, V, P]` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120836/cannot-prove-equivalence-with-a-path-dependent-type or `TL[In][O] = MyTypeclass[In] { type Out = O }` for any type class in type-level calculations, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418623/express-function-of-arbitrary-arity-in-vanilla-scala-3 I guess `[X] =>> [Y] =>> ...` are currently a little premature and not so useful without `type TL[X][Y]`, `def foo[X][Y]`, `def foo[F[_][_]]`

Comment: @Max  and it's written *"no special provision is made to infer type arguments to such curried type lambdas"* in https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html